# YouTube embedded video issue

Tags: php, youtube, embed, bbcode

I want to embed the YouTube video on my website. The problem is with timeline and origin link properties. For example, I have some text and 2 `bbCode` video tags, one with timeline and 2nd without timeline:

```
This is just a test example.

[youtube]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHLE2LTAItw&t=53s[/youtube]

[youtube]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHLE2LTAItw[/youtube]
```

**Code:**

```
if (preg_match_all("/\[youtube\]((\s|.)+?)\[\/youtube\]/i", $text, $matches)) {
    $allMatches = count($matches[0]);
        
        if (is_array($matches[0]) && $allMatches > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $allMatches; $i++) {
                 $text = str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $text);

                 if (strpos($matches[0][$i], "&amp;t=") !== false) {
                     $text = str_replace("&amp;t=", "?start=", $text);
                     $text = preg_replace("#s\[\/youtube\]#i", "&enablejsapi=1&origin=". HAZELFENCES_WEBSITE ."[/youtube]", $text);
                 } else {
                     $text = preg_replace("#\[\/youtube\]#i", "?enablejsapi=1&origin=". HAZELFENCES_WEBSITE ."[/youtube]", $text);
                 }
            }

            $text = preg_replace("/\[youtube\]((\s|.)+?)\[\/youtube\]/i", "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"510\" src=\"\\1\" loading=\"lazy\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", $text);
        }
    }
    
    return $text;
```

The `iframe src` from the first video returns as: `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xHLE2LTAItw?start=53&enablejsapi=1&origin=https://test.com?enablejsapi=1&origin=https://test.com"` which is wrong. It should be:
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/xHLE2LTAItw?start=53&enablejsapi=1&origin=https://test.com`

The video link without timeline must be:
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/xHLE2LTAItw?enablejsapi=1&origin=https://test.com`, which is correct using my code. The only issue is with timeline videos.

Please note, this issue is only occurs when 2 video links are available. One with timeline and the second one without timeline.

For example: https://3v4l.org/JTAUp

Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce, https://3v4l.org/Yelmp - generated iframe src is `https://www.youtube.com/embed/xHLE2LTAItw?start=53&enablejsapi=1&origin=https://test.com`

Comment: @CBroe
The issue is only occurs when 2 video links are available, one with timeline & 1 without. I think, I have an idea.

Comment: @CBroe

Try this code to reproduce it: https://3v4l.org/XAlZT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It's a bit tricky but I have finally fixed it by using `RegExp` and `preg_replace` function. First of all, I have checked for the video link with timeline and then `preg_replace` the `&t=00s[/youtube]` with `?start=\\1&enablejsapi=1&origin=". HAZELFENCES_WEBSITE`.

Secondly, I checked for the video without timeline and `preg_replace` the `/embed/xHLE2LTAItw[/youtube]` with `/\\1\\2?enablejsapi=1&origin=". HAZELFENCES_WEBSITE ."[/youtube]`.

**My code:**

```
$text = str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $text);
$isVideoWithTimeline = preg_match("#\[youtube\](http|https):\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/([a-z]+\?v=|[a-z]+\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(&|&[a-zA-Z]+;)[a-zA-Z]=\d+s\[\/youtube\]#si", $text);
    
if ($isVideoWithTimeline > 0) {
    $text = preg_replace("#&amp;t=([0-9]+)s\[\/youtube\]#si", "?start=\\1&enablejsapi=1&origin=". HAZELFENCES_WEBSITE ."[/youtube]", $text);
}
    
$isVideoWithoutTimeline = preg_match("#\[youtube\](http|https):\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/([a-z]+\?v=|[a-z]+\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\[\/youtube\]#si", $text);
    
if ($isVideoWithoutTimeline > 0) {
    $text = preg_replace("#/([a-z]+\?v=|[a-z]+\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\[\/youtube\]#si", "/\\1\\2?enablejsapi=1&origin=". HAZELFENCES_WEBSITE ."[/youtube]", $text);
}
    
$text = preg_replace("/\[youtube\]((\s|.)+?)\[\/youtube\]/i", "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"510\" src=\"\\1\" loading=\"lazy\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", $text);
return $text;
```

Now, everything works well. The issue is resolved.